# SCSS: Bem and recommended directory structure?

Tags: css, sass, bem

I have started updating my styling side wide to BEM. So far I am loving it, but I am having an issue separating the scss into a correct directory structure. BEM takes care of my naming conventions for my classes, but I wanted to try and get some order of why I am storing my scss.

I thought about two things, the directory structure could be separated by Component but maybe this doesn't fit well BEM considering there is not a 1 to 1 mapping between block level elements and components.

I presume there will be some sort of structure for storing _base, _variables, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend sitting your component files next to each other, like this;

```
├── src
|   ├── _modules              
|   |   └── link
|   |       ├── __tests__
|   |       |   └── link.spec.js
|   |       ├── link.html
|   |       ├── link.js
|   |       └── link.scss
```

Which does fit very nicely with BEM way of thinking. I think the no 1 to 1 mapping you're talking about is the concept in BEM that you shouldn't try and replicate the DOM in your CSS. Anything that doesn't belong in a component folder, can live in a "core" component.

There's a very good Yeoman generator called Yeogurt https://github.com/larsonjj/generator-yeogurt that builds this type of structure (as well as a bunch of other things) for you.

Comment: What would the contents of link.html be, hypothetically?

Comment: @EdmundReed this is the template HTML that makes up the module. So, this might look like:

`<a href="{{url}}" class="link">{{name}}</a>`

If you were using mustache templates

Note, that Yeogurt uses jade (now pug).